# nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size

Tags: nginx, webserver

I'm in the process of setting up a new server. The web server of my choice is NGINX. I want to add the domain (e.g. `example.com`) as a virtual host. I already have two other domains in there and it works fine, but when I try to add the above mentioned domain and start the server it gives me:

> Job failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.

I thought it was because of the dashes, so I tried just various other domains with and without hyphens, but no luck. Same error. what could be causing this? I also tried rebooting, I am really at a loss here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have played around a bit and found out, that, when I only put one domain in, it works. But when I put another domain in, it stops. Here is the output in status:

```bash
[root@netzmelone nginx]# systemctl status nginx
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun, 16 Dec 2012 11:38:08 +0000; 7s ago
     Process: 14239 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; -s quit (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Process: 14232 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 14242 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g pid /run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Main PID: 14234 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/nginx.service

Dec 16 11:38:08 netzmelone nginx[14242]: nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
Dec 16 11:38:08 netzmelone nginx[14242]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Have you looked at any logs?

Comment: Which logs should I be looking at?

Comment: or you can use simply your domain name inside of your server_name.

Answer (score 418, accepted):

This is most likely happening because of the long domain name. You can fix this by adding

```bash
server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
```

at the top of your `http` block (probably located in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`). I quote from the nginx documentation what to do when this error appears:

> In this case, the directive value should be increased to the next power of two.

So in your case it should become 64. If you still get the same error, try increasing to 128 and further.

Reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization

Comment: Interestingly, I had to use 64 even though my particular Nginx error message was instructing me to use 32.

Comment: Same as @Ryan -- NGINX was telling me to use 64, but I needed 128 to make it work.

Comment: @jerzy Some mundane morning detail was missed, apparently.

Comment: @jerzy Even though the slightly ambiguous wording of that error message kind of suggests otherwise, it was probably designed to include the **current value**, not to instruct you what value to use.

Comment: @jerzy how would one go about increasing this in userdata when provisioning an ec2 instance. so basically in bash script?

Comment: I am guessing nginx is rather saying to increase the size, and then is concatening your actual size at the end of the message ? it really looks like the `key +" : "+ get(key)` kind of error message.

Answer (score 61):

- open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with write privileges
- uncomment or add `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`
- restart nginx `sudo service nginx restart`

If the error still persists:

- increase `server_names_hash_bucket_size` in steps 128, 256, 512, and so on (increasing by a power of 2 each time). eg. `server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;`
- restart the nginx each time until error is gone (error will always be the same no matter what value you already set)

Comment: thanks for suggesting the incremental approach. nginx's message kept saying set it to `64` :S

Comment: Thanks, by incrementing, everything went well !!

Comment: Run "sudo nginx -t" to check if configuration is correct or not before restarting/reloading the nginx. Use "sudo service nginx reload" to reload the configuration rather than restarting.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds perhaps a bit random, but it might help an nginx newb like myself.
I got this error when I left off a `;` on the `server_name` line.

had:

```
server_name    www.mydomain.com  
access_log     /var/log/nginx/www.mydomain.com;
```

fix:

```
server_name    www.mydomain.com;  
access_log     /var/log/nginx/www.mydomain.com;
```

All directives in nginx config files must end with a `;`
I often highlight `;`s in my file before saving/uploading as a final check after editing.

*(To highlight, I use `Find All`: `;`)*

Answer (score 10):

This is how I solved:

```
cd /etc/nginx/

sudo nano nginx.conf
```

- --uncomment or add server_names_hash_bucket_size 64 --
- --increase server_names_hash_bucket_size "164" --

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/

sudo nginx -t
```

- if all it's ok

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thanks ```server_names_hash_bucket_size "164"``` works  for me, im hosting a 2 sites under the same port (just for demo only)

Answer (score 1):

open your nginx.conf file, it's in this director /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
it's the global nginx configuration.

vi into the nginx.conf and add this line to the http block
"server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;"

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't have issue with bucketsize. This happen you have previously created symlink in  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and you are trying to renew or reinstall ssl with certbot.  delete the file from /etc/nginx/sites-enable/your-domain-conf-file
and rerun the the certbot command as below

```
 sudo certbot --nginx -d your-domain-name.com
```

It should work.