# nginx -t fails due to server_names_hash_bucket_size - but changing the size does not resolve the issue

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I am launching a Django application using gunicorn and nginx through AWS. I set up the gunicorn configurations with no errors. I created a new nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and I ran `sudo nginx -t` to see test and I get the following errors: 
`nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`
I uncommented the `server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64` in nginx configurations at `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and this still does not change my error and I am not able to restart my server (I am trying to set up a supervisor to ensure gunicorn is always running in the background) 
For reference: 
 **django.conf:**

```
server { 
   listen 80; server name 34.212.49.238; 
   location / { 
      include proxy_params; 
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Django_webapp/app.sock; 
   } 
}
```

I also ran `systemctl status nginx.service`: 
[image]

I am a novice at server troubleshooting and really appreciate your help

Comment: Can you take a peek at solutions in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895933/nginx-emerg-could-not-build-the-server-names-hash-you-should-increase-server

Answer (score 0):

Solved it
I created an older config file in `etc/nginx/sites-available` which I had deleted. But used the same code in a new config file (same DNS, port, etc.). While the config file was deleted from `etc/nginx/sites-available`, it still existed in `etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. So double-check all changes made in either of these files are reflected on the other.