# nginx gives me error when I change public IPv4 address to DNS

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-ingress, nginx-location

I am setting up my ec2 machine on AWS and when I change server_name from `x.xxx.xx.xxx` to `ec2-x-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`, and run
`sudo service nginx restart`
it gives me

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The nginx sites-enabled file

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
  }
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Try configuration test via `nginx -t` command. Check the error log, by default `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. Update the post and add more information if you cannot solve the problem.

Comment: What is output of systemctl status nginx.service

Comment: if the problem appeared only after updating `server_name`, maybe you forgot to put the `;` at the end?

Comment: @qwsj no, there is no typos I checked that 100 times

Comment: The answer to this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895933/nginx-emerg-could-not-build-the-server-names-hash-you-should-increase-server